# Bulk json data is unable retrive in http webage hosted by lighttpd

Tags: python, json, apache, lighttpd

Following sample python code retrieves bulk json data(>30000) and prints it.
Python execution is working fine, but when I host it with lighttpd, I am getting "500 internal server error" in web browser. I am attaching the strace and lighttpd debug logs. Could some one help fixing this issue?

```
data = table.find()
x=[]
for each in data:
    x.append(each) 
print json.dumps(x)
```

strace log:

```
error 500 internal server error  ioctl(6, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
read(10, "0, \"name\": \"10\", \"stop\": 57}, "..., 4159) = 4159
ioctl(6, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
read(10, "_id\": 18189, \"b\": 993, \"name"..., 4159) = 4159
ioctl(6, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
read(10, " \"name\": \"4\", \"add\": 220}, {\""..., 4159) = 2623
mmap(NULL, 2301952, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f89d506f000
ioctl(6, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
read(10, "", 4159)                      = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, 10, {0, {u32=0, u64=0}}) = 0
close(10)                               = 0
munmap(0x7f89d506f000, 2301952)         = 0
wait4(11093, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 11093
stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=265, ...}) = 0
write(3, "2015-11-09 23:18:19: (response.c"..., 204) = 204
setsockopt(6, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, [1], 4) = 0
writev(6, [{"HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Err"..., 146}, {"", 0}, {"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"is"..., 369}], 3) = 515
setsockopt(6, SOL_TCP, TCP_CORK, [0], 4) = 0
ioctl(6, FIONREAD, [0])                 = 0
read(6, 0x1075e40, 4159)                = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 6, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=6, u64=6}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 6, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=6, u64=6}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(5, EPOLL_CTL_MOD, 6, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLERR|EPOLLHUP, {u32=6, u64=6}}) = 0
epoll_wait(5, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=6, u64=6}}}, 1025, 1000) = 1
```

ligttpd debug log:

```
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (response.c.730) -- handling subrequest
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (response.c.731) Path         : /home/ubuntu/App/run.py
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block ===
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: true
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block ===
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.537) 2 (cached) result: false
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (mod_access.c.135) -- mod_access_uri_handler called
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block ===
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: true
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block ===
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.537) 2 (cached) result: false
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (mod_compress.c.745) -- handling file as static file
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block ===
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.537) 1 (cached) result: true
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block ===
2015-11-10 19:54:42: (configfile-glue.c.537) 2 (cached) result: false
2015-11-10 19:54:43: (response.c.128) Response-Header:
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error^M
Content-Type: text/html^M
Content-Length: 369^M
Date: Tue, 10 Nov 2015 14:24:43 GMT^M
Server: lighttpd/1.4.33^M
^M

2015-11-10 19:54:54: (request.c.307) fd: 11 request-len: 115
GET /test HTTP/1.1^M
host: 172.31.17.66^M
User-Agent: ELB-HealthChecker/1.0^M
Accept: */*^M
Connection: keep-alive^M
^M

2015-11-10 19:54:54: (response.c.249) run condition
2015-11-10 19:54:54: (configfile-glue.c.579) === start of condition block ===
2015-11-10 19:54:54: (configfile-glue.c.273) 2 global/HTTPurl=~^/ nej
```

Comment: The connection to the backend is misconfigured in lighttpd.conf. Double-check the ports, paths allowed in the proxy block etc.